# Put something out to tender

Tags: grammar, prepositions, parts-of-speech, intransitive-verbs

> **[TENDER](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/tender)**: (intransitive) followed by *for*: to make a formal offer
> or estimate for (a job or contract).
>
> noun: the act or an instance of tendering; offer.

What does **tender** mean in [put something out to tender](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/put-something-out-to-tender) ?

Comment: Rather similar to _be open to offers_.

Answer (score 1):

It means that in answer to a formal procedure making explicit that someone (company, business) is accepting propositions for doing a particular job for them, these propositions having to do with the means intended to accomplish  this job and the price that is required (if that price has not been fixed), you make such a proposition.

Comment: what part of speech are **tender** and **to**  in _put something out to tender_ ?

Comment: When you put something out to tender, you make it (at least semi-) public for others to submit tenders (bids) on doing that thing. So, three companies may tender three different prices on that opportunity.

Comment: @GJC "To" is a preposition and "tender" a verb. ([OALD, 1](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/tender_3))

Comment: I thought that structure was only used with transitive verbs, but the relevant meaning of tender is intransitive here

Comment: @GJC I see what you mean; "something" is the object of "tender" in this construction; that seems inescapable. I see that there is a noun to match the verb ([OALD, 1](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/tender_2)). In fact this definition contains the construction, which show that "tender" is here a noun and not a verb. Sharp thinking!

Comment: Wiktionary also has _put out **for** tender_ https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tender#See_also

Comment: _New regulations force a hospital to put a service out to tender **by** private sector companies_  https://books.google.es/books?id=WB8NxwzBPPgC&lpg=PA125&dq=%22regulations%20force%20a%20hospital%20to%20put%20a%20service%20%2C%20which%20had%20hitherto%20been%20provided%20in%20house%20%2C%20out%20to%20tender%20by%20private%20sector%20companies%22&hl=es&pg=PA125#v=onepage&q=%22regulations%20force%20a%20hospital%20to%20put%20a%20service%20,%20which%20had%20hitherto%20been%20provided%20in%20house%20,%20out%20to%20tender%20by%20private%20sector%20companies%22&f=false